# How can I iterate specific rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, iteration

I want to iterate specific rows based on the number of the list factors in the `Content_ID_group` column.

For example, as the first row of the table below has six factors in its list in `Content_ID_group` column, I want to make the other columns (`Event Name`, `Media`) iterate six times.

So as the original dataframe I have:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> graph = pd.DataFrame({"Event Name": ["ord", "inflow"], "Media":["google", "appier"], "Content Id_group":[[1,2,3,4,5,6], 0]})
>>> print(graph)
  Event Name   Media    Content Id_group
0        ord  google  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
1     inflow  appier                   0
```

and this is the output I would like:

```
  Event Name   Media Content Id_group
0        ord  google                1
0        ord  google                2
0        ord  google                3
0        ord  google                4
0        ord  google                5
0        ord  google                6
1     inflow  appier                0
```

So this is my code. It just keeps running, not giving out the result. So I guess it is an infinite loop.

Can someone help?

- `graph` is the graph I defined.
- `g_whole` is the dataframe that has to contain all the iteration result that I defined.

```
g_whole=pd.DataFrame()

for g in range(len(graph)):
    if type(graph['Content ID_group'][0]) == list:
        loop=len(graph['Content ID_group'][0])
        for l in range(loop):
            itt=graph.loc[g]
            g_whole.append(itt)
        
    elif type(graph['Content ID_group'][0]) == int:
        g_whole.append(graph['Content ID_group'][0])
print(g_whole)
```

Comment: you need to check the proposed answers, and approve or provide feedback if they solved your problem or not

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd

graph = pd.DataFrame({"Event Name": ["ord", "inflow"], "Media":["google", "appier"], "Content Id_group":[[1,2,3,4,5,6], 0]})

print(graph)
  Event Name   Media    Content Id_group
0        ord  google  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
1     inflow  appier                   0

g_whole = graph.explode("Content Id_group")

print(g_whole)
  Event Name   Media Content Id_group
0        ord  google                1
0        ord  google                2
0        ord  google                3
0        ord  google                4
0        ord  google                5
0        ord  google                6
1     inflow  appier                0
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `Content ID_group` contains a real list, you can use `explode`:

```
>>> type(graph.at[0, 'Content ID_group'])
list

>>> graph.explode('Content ID_group')
  Event Name   Media Content ID_group
0        ord  google                1
0        ord  google                2
0        ord  google                3
0        ord  google                4
0        ord  google                5
0        ord  google                6
1     inflow  appier                0
```

If `Contains ID_group` contains strings, you have to `eval` first:

```
>>> type(graph.at[0, 'Content ID_group'])
str

>>> graph['Content ID_group'] = graph['Content ID_group'].apply(pd.eval)

>>> graph.explode('Content ID_group')
  Event Name   Media Content ID_group
0        ord  google                1
0        ord  google                2
0        ord  google                3
0        ord  google                4
0        ord  google                5
0        ord  google                6
1     inflow  appier                0
```